# iphone code - custom table instead of default one

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm using a default style table (`UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`) 
i want to add more then one `detailTextLabel` in each row,
how can i customize it?

code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

// Leave cells empty if there's no data yet
if (nodeCount > 0)
{
    // Set up the cell...
    ARecord *aRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = aRecord.lDate;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aRecord.WNum;

    // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
    //(!aRecord.appIcon) - use icon
    if (!aRecord.appIcon)
    {
        if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:aRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];                
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = aRecord.appIcon;
    }

}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to add a `UILabel` to the `cell.contentView`. You would do this when you initially create the cell. I've found two things to be especially helpful: to lay out the label on a table cell in a throwaway document in Interface Builder to determine the initial frame. It's also especially helpful to set the `autoresizingMask` so that the label will be resized appropriately when the cell is resized (due to autorotation, going into edit mode, etc.).

Finally, you'll need to set the table view's `rowHeight` to a higher value to accommodate the larger cells, otherwise you'll end up with overlapping cells.

Also, set a `tag` on your label to make it easy to retrieve with `viewWithTag:` when you go to update the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the labels to `cell.contentView`.